# PHP - Proper way to add data into nested array specific index

Tags: php, arrays, json

What would be the proper / practical way to add information into nested array?

I have a problem pushing a data to specific index of array. I have foreach loop for my JSON file that I'm reading with PHP.

```
$array[] = array();
foreach($json["data"] as $inx => $key) {

        $field1 = $json["data"][$inx]["field1"];
        $field2 = $json["data"][$inx]["field2"];

        array_push($array[$field], $field2);
}
```

Data should look similar:

```
18732($field1) {
    123($field2),
    1234($field2),
    12345($field2),
    0983($field2),
    239823($field2),
    238742($field2)
}
```

How do I merge duplicate `$field1`'s data to array which is "named" as `$field1`?

The error message is:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   D:\Installed\Xampp\htdocs\includes\core.php on line 71

Comment: You already tried your own code, please state what is wrong with the result.

Comment: Sorry I was so confused so I forgot to add information about that: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\Installed\Xampp\htdocs\includes\core.php on line 71

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information directly to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks almost right, but you have:

1. A syntax error: `$array[]= array();`,
2. A typo:`$field` vs `$field1`
3. And the `$array[$field1]` is not defined when it is first accessed.

Corrected code:

```
$array = array();
foreach($json["data"] as $inx => $key) {

        $field1 = $json["data"][$inx]["field1"];
        $field2 = $json["data"][$inx]["field2"];

        if (!isset($array[$field1]))
            $array[$field1] = array();

        array_push($array[$field1], $field2);
}
```

Comment: About the defining you were talking about helped me to solve the issue. I had to add "isset" check about that if the array index is defined. If not. It will define that and then push information to array with specific index. Thank you a lot.